# 8X1 MUX using Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to write a design and a testbench Verilog code for a 8X1 MUX with input width of 8 bits each.
Here is my design code :

```
module MUX8_1(
  input [7:0] a[8], 
  input   [2:0] sel,
  output reg [7:0] y

);
  always @ (sel) begin
    case (sel [2:0]) 
      3'b000 : begin y [7:0]<=  a [0];end 
      3'b001 : begin y [7:0]<=  a [1];end
      3'b010 : begin y [7:0]<=  a [2];end
      3'b011 : begin y [7:0]<=  a [3];end
      3'b100 : begin y [7:0]<=  a [4];end
      3'b101 : begin y [7:0]<=  a [5];end
      3'b110 : begin y [7:0]<=  a [6];end
      3'b111 : begin y [7:0]<=  a [7];end
    default : begin $display ("error " ) ; end
    endcase 
  end
endmodule: MUX8_1
```

Here is my testbench

```
module testbench_MUX();


  reg clk;
  reg [7:0] d[8];

  reg [2:0] select;

  wire z ; 


  MUX8_1 mux(.a(d) , .sel(select),.y(z));


  initial begin 
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
  end 

  initial begin 
    clk =1;
    forever begin 
      /* toggle the clk every 50 time units  which is configured in 
      the simulation to be 1ns*/
      clk = #50 ~clk;
    end 
  end


  initial begin // {
    d[0]= 'h00;
    d[1]= 'hA1;
    d[2]= 'hA2;
    d[3]= 'hA3;
    d[4]= 'hB4;
    d[5]= 'hB5;
    d[6]= 'hB6;
    d[7]= 'hB7;


    for ( int i=0 ; i<=7 ; i++ ) begin
      @ ( posedge clk);
        select = i;
      end

     @ ( posedge clk);
        $finish;
    end // } 

  always @(z) begin 
    $display ("at t=%0t : select='b%3b, output= 'h%0h",$time,select,z) ;
      end 
endmodule
```

However the output is wrong :

```
  # KERNEL: at t=100 : select='b000, output= 'h0
# KERNEL: at t=200 : select='b001, output= 'h1
# KERNEL: at t=300 : select='b010, output= 'h0
# KERNEL: at t=400 : select='b011, output= 'h1
# KERNEL: at t=500 : select='b100, output= 'h0
# KERNEL: at t=600 : select='b101, output= 'h1
# KERNEL: at t=700 : select='b110, output= 'h0
# KERNEL: at t=800 : select='b111, output= 'h1
```

So where is the problem ?

Comment: the third example here may help ... http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/vbehave1.html

Comment: Your title says "VHDL" but your code samples are Verilog. Can you edit the question or title to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not VHDL. It is not legal Verilog either because input `a` is two dimensional (ports can only be single bits and one dimensional vectors in Verilog). It is legal SystemVerilog; the successor of Verilog.

The reason `z` only has the value of 0 or 1 is because it was defined as a single bit (`wire z;`). There should be a compile warning. Change it to 8-bits (`wire [7:0] z;`) and that should fix the output.

---

Other note:
`always @(sel)` should be `always @*` (or `always_comb` for SystemVerilog). The former is not sensitive to changes on `a` for simulation. The latter figures out the sensitivity list automatically.